# How to delete partitions in unattended.xml Windows 10

Tags: xml, windows-10, partitioning, wds, unattend-file

I'm having an issue with deleting all partitions in a WDS unattened.xml file

```
<DiskConfiguration>
            <Disk wcm:action="add">
                <CreatePartitions>
                    <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Order>1</Order>
                        <Type>Primary</Type>
                        <Size>500</Size>
                    </CreatePartition>
                    <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Order>2</Order>
                        <Type>Primary</Type>
                        <Extend>true</Extend>
                    </CreatePartition>
                </CreatePartitions>
                <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
                <ModifyPartitions>
                    <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Active>true</Active>
                        <Format>NTFS</Format>
                        <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                        <Order>1</Order>
                        <Label>System Reserved</Label>
                        <Extend>false</Extend>
                    </ModifyPartition>
                    <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Extend>true</Extend>
                        <Format>NTFS</Format>
                        <Label>Windows</Label>
                        <Letter>C</Letter>
                        <Order>2</Order>
                        <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                    </ModifyPartition>
                </ModifyPartitions>
            </Disk>
            <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
        </DiskConfiguration>
```

This is supposed to wipe out all partitions, create the new partition, and modify the partition.